# RODBC is not working in Rstudio version 4.2.2

Tags: r, rodbc

Currently I am busy with a R-Studio upgrade. My current version is 4.0.2, I am upgrading to 4.2.2. The ODBC connection that worked fine in version 4.0.2 is not working anymore in version 4.2.2. Are there changes in version 4.2.2 that can couse an ODBC connection problem?

I use the foloowing code to create the connection. This code works in version 4.0.2 but not in version 4.2.2:

```
library(RODBC)

connection.name <- odbcConnect("ODBC connection", uid="user.name", pwd="password")

dataframe <- sqlQuery(connection.name, paste("SELECT * FROM table"))

odbcClose(connection.name)
```

Comment: did you consider using [DBI](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/r-packages/dbi/) instead? Supported by RStudio, and known to be much [faster](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/1ea2a1de11fc1f0aa391f9977766ccec)

Comment: Are you sure your RStudio Version is 4.0.2 and your want to upgrade RStudio to V. 4.2.2?

Comment: I made a mistake with the versions. I am currently running R-Studio 2022.07.02 and updating to 2022-12-0.